# how to make an prompt mandatory

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a prompt alert with a button and I need that alert to be closed only when "done" button is clicked. Currently I am able to get a prompt window with a text box and a button. When I tap on the screen somewhere the prompt gets closed. I want my prompt window be closed only when I tap the "done" button.

```
presentPrompt() {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Name your audio file ',
                inputs: [
                    {
                        name: 'FileName',
                        placeholder: "Enter a string"
                    }
                ],
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Done',
                    handler: data => {
                        console.log("clicked done")
                    } 

                }
            ] 
        }); 

    alert.present();
}
```

Alert to be closed on alert button clicked and also is there any possibility to add validation to the input box. could someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/) you can use `enableBackdropDismiss: false`

```
     let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Name your audio file ',
            inputs: [
                {
                    name: 'FileName',
                    placeholder: "Enter a string"
                }
            ],
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Done',
                handler: data => {
                    console.log("clicked done")
                } 

            }
        ],
        enableBackdropDismiss: false
    });
```

Comment: could i able to set "required" validator to my input in prompt

Comment: This is another question on another topic. However the answer is no, from the same ionic article *If you require a complex form UI which doesn't fit within the guidelines of an alert then we recommend building the form within a modal instead.*